# No contabiliza el espacio liberado

Tags: java

En el siguiente método hace una limpieza de la carpeta de archivos temporales con un objeto `File` y da un resultado al usuario. El problema que me encuentro es que borra elementos y contabiliza el número de archivos pero no de capacidad en bytes en `espacioLiberado`.

```
        private void jButton_LimpiarDiscoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    // Especifica la ubicación de la carpeta de archivos temporales
    String tempFolderPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

    // Crea un objeto File para la carpeta de archivos temporales
    File tempFolder = new File(tempFolderPath);

    int archivosBorrados = 0;
    long espacioLiberado = 0;

    // Verifica si la carpeta de archivos temporales existe
    if (tempFolder.exists() && tempFolder.isDirectory()) {
        // Lista los archivos en la carpeta de archivos temporales
        File[] files = tempFolder.listFiles();

        // Itera a través de los archivos y elimínalos
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                if (file.delete()) {
                    archivosBorrados++;
                    espacioLiberado += file.length();
                    System.out.println("Se ha eliminado el archivo: " + file.getName());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No se pudo eliminar el archivo: " + file.getName());
                    System.out.println("Carpeta de archivos temporales: " + tempFolderPath);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    String mensaje = "Se han eliminado " + archivosBorrados + " archivos. Espacio liberado: " + espacioLiberado + " bytes.";

    // Muestra un mensaje al usuario con la información
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje, "Resultado de la limpieza", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Espero haberme explicado bien, cualquier duda o sugerencia con respeto por favor.
Gracias!

Comment: El método funciona perfectamente... estás usando file.delete() ANTES de mirar el peso del archivo... un archivo borrado no pesa nada :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes obtener el tamaño del archivo en bytes antes de eliminarlo, ya que si obtienes su medida después de llamar el método `file.delete()`, la medida será siempre 0. También puedes hacer uso de la clase [DirectoryStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) para realizar una iteración de esta tarea de una forma más rápida.

```
 private void jButton_LimpiarDiscoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
// Especifica la ubicación de la carpeta de archivos temporales
String tempFolderPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

// Crea un objeto File para la carpeta de archivos temporales
File tempFolder = new File(tempFolderPath);

int archivosBorrados = 0;
long espacioLiberado = 0;

// Verifica si la carpeta de archivos temporales existe
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(tempFolderPath))) {
        for (Path entry : stream) {
            File file = entry.toFile(); //* Obtiene medida de archivo en bytes
            if (file.isFile()) { //*Elimina archivo 
                espacioLiberado += file.length();
                if (file.delete()) {
                    archivosBorrados++;
                    System.out.println("Se ha eliminado el archivo: " + file.getName());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No se pudo eliminar el archivo: " + file.getName());
                    System.out.println("Carpeta de archivos temporales: " + tempFolderPath);
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

String mensaje = "Se han eliminado " + archivosBorrados + " archivos. Espacio liberado: " + espacioLiberado + " bytes.";

// Muestra un mensaje al usuario con la información
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje, "Resultado de la limpieza", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

---

Answer (score 3):

El problema está en que estás cogiendo el tamaño del fichero después de haberlo borrado, con lo cual siempre te devuelve 0. Basta con que cojas el tamaño antes de borrarlo y lo sumes si el borrado ha sido exitoso. He añadido la variable `fileSize` y hecho una pequeña modificación en tu código

```
 for (File file : files) {
     if (file.isFile()) {
         long fileSize = file.length();
         if (file.delete()) {
             archivosBorrados++;
             espacioLiberado += fileSize;
             System.out.println("Se ha eliminado el archivo: " + file.getName());
         } else {
             System.out.println("No se pudo eliminar el archivo: " + file.getName());
             System.out.println("Carpeta de archivos temporales: " + tempFolderPath);
          }
     }
 }
```